# C++ type converting issue

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int aaa(int a) {
    cout << a * 0.3 << endl;
    return a * 0.3;
}

int main()
{
    cout << aaa(35000);
}
```

It prints out:

```
10500
10499
```

Why output differs?

I have a workaround to use "return a * 3 / 10;" but I don't like it.

Edit:

Found that doing "return float(a * 0.3);" gives expected value;

Comment: `cout << a * 0.3` use type double as the result. but in second output you pass the result from int type filter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of 0.3*35000 is a floating point number, just slightly less than 10500. When printed it is rounded to 10500, but when coerced into an int the fractional digits are discarded, resulting in 10499.

Comment: Is it not compiler specific? gcc prints 10500 in both cases

Comment: It is. In fact 10500 can be represented *exactly* as a floating point number, and if the multiplication is made with 64 bits the result should be 10500 *always*. The thing is, some systems use 80-bit precision for intermediate values. This makes 0.3 slightly less than 3/10, and when the result of the multiplication is rounded it is wrong in the last bit.

Answer (score 6):

`int * double` expression yields double, that's what the first thing prints.
Then you convert to `int` chopping the remaining part (even if it's almost there, sitting at 10500-DBL_EPSILON), and pass that back. The second prints that value.

float-int conversions should be made with care, better not at all.

Answer (score 2):

`a * 0.3` has type `double`. The call inside `aaa` calls

```
ostream& operator<< (double val);
```

whereas the one outside calls

```
ostream& operator<< (int val);
```

You'd get a warning (if you turn them on - I suggest you do) that the implicit cast from `double` to `int` isn't recommended.

Comment: Tell me more about -I i can't find it in my Code::Blocks compiler settings. At least how to Google it.

Comment: @user2534633 I as in myself... I suggest you turn them on :)